# Error when running puppeteer-core AWS layer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I am not 100% where the issue is when I attempt to create a puppeteer-core layer for AWS. On a Linux box I install the package, zip it up, and then create a layer in AWS Lambda.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-25:~$ npm i puppeteer-core
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-25:~$ npm pack ./node_modules/puppeteer-core/
npm notice 
npm notice   puppeteer-core@1.11.0 
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
puppeteer-core-1.11.0.tgz
```

Then I create the .zip file for upload to AWS layers

```
mkdir --parents nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer-core-1.11.0/ && \
tar --directory nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer-core-1.11.0/ --extract --file 
puppeteer-core-1.11.0*.tgz --strip-components=1 && \
rm puppeteer-core-1.11.0*.tgz && \
zip -9 --filesync --move --recurse-paths _/puppeteer-core.zip nodejs/
```

But I get the following error when attempting to run this [sample code](https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda) which makes me think there is something missing from the package when I am creating it?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'debug'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/puppeteer-core-1.11.0/lib/helper.js:18:20)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing dependencies (debug being the first one) that NPM installed for the puppeteer-core package in the `nodejs/node_modules`. Make sure to include those dependencies in your layer and it should work.

Comment: Hi @juanald_reagan what do you mean `include those dependencies in your layer`?

Comment: Ok, I removed all files from `node_modules` and run `npm i` again. That helped.